# Cannot run JavaFX application from terminal

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to run a JavaFx application from the terminal, it fails to run showing `Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.javafx.HelloWorld`

Here is my code:

```
package com.test.javafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Compilation does not show any error and is successful. But trying to run the application results in `Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.javafx.HelloWorld`. However when I run a simple application, it runs without any errors.

Here is the javap output:

```
Compiled from "HelloWorld.java"
public class com.test.javafx.HelloWorld extends javafx.application.Application {
  public com.test.javafx.HelloWorld();
  public void start(javafx.stage.Stage);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

I have also tried the following:

```
java -cp /home/itachi/mycategories/installs/devel/java/jdk/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar;." com.test.javafx.HelloWorld
```

but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue

## Issue

While installing some software using Linux package manager, OpenJDK JRE Headless (as a dependancy package) was installed. This was confirmed by running:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
$ java com.test.javafx.HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.javafx.HelloWorld
```

If I run using this OpenJDK JVM, it shows the error.

## Fix

Changed the `PATH` variable so that now Oracle's JVM is default.

```
$ ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
$ ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java com.test.javafx.HelloWorld => [Now the program runs]

[After Changing the ~/.bashrc file]
$ . ~/.bashrc
java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
$ java com.test.javafx.HelloWorld => [Now the program runs]
```

## Unknown Factor

Still, I am not sure why OpenJDK JVM throws `Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.javafx.HelloWorld`, because running Oracle JVM from the same location renders the application.

Comment: That would not give the error message you posted in the question.

Comment: @James_D I have updated the answer. Hope that answers yours question.

Comment: Did you intend the output from `java -version` in the first code block to be identical to the output in the second code block?

Comment: @James_D Copied the wrong block and pasted. Now updated the answer

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. I still really don't get why it is saying it can't find the class you defined... that just sounds like the classpath is messed up. If it said it couldn't find something in `javafx.*` or `com.sun.javafx.*` it would make sense. However, it is what it is.

Comment: Yeah, a ClassNotFoundException would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Similar worked for me. My Linux distro had another SDK version on there. I needed to specify that version or change the default version.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when java cannot find your compiled classes in classpath. Try `java -cp <path to .class files> HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this trying the stock JavaFX HelloWorld example, and it looks like this is a known low-priority bug with OpenJDK/JavaFX.  Commenting out the "package" declaration at the top of HelloWorld.java and re-compiling lets it run without problems.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163089

I hit this on XUbuntu 16.04/Java 1.8.0_144.